# what does this line mean " operators.indexOf(btnVal) > -1"?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript calculator from this site http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/javascript-css3-calculator
but i got stuck in a code
**operators.indexOf(btnVal) > -1**
What does this line mean?

Comment: `indexOf` will return the position(starts from `0`) of the element in the array if present else `-1`.. So __operators.indexOf(btnVal) > -1__ will be evaluated as `true` if element is there in the array...

Comment: You could just look it up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: i didn't understand why use greater then, can you explain this?

Comment: It is just a basic Math... Indexes/Positions which are equals to or greater than 0 are going to be greater than `-1`.. Developers also prefer `Arr.indexOf != -1`

Comment: If the index is >= 0 then it exists. If the index is < 0 then it doesn't exist.

Comment: if i write "operators.indexOf(btnVal)"  without >-1 ,it will be right?

Comment: thanks everybody  for your solution

Answer (score 0):

`operators` is either a string or an array.
`indexOf` finds the index of the queried substring / value in the string / array.

[String.Prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

[Array.Prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

It returns `-1` if the substring / value is not found. `> -1` is a check for the opposite, i.e. the substring / value exists in the string / array.

Examples:

```js
console.log('xyz'.indexOf('z')); // 2
console.log('xyz'.indexOf('y')); // 1
console.log('xyz'.indexOf('yz')); // 1
console.log('xyz'.indexOf('q')); // -1

console.log([1, 'abc', true].indexOf('abc')); // 1
console.log([1, 'abc', true].indexOf('true')); // -1
console.log([1, 'abc', true].indexOf(true)); // 2
console.log([1, 'abc', true].indexOf('a')); // -1
console.log([1, 'abc', true].indexOf(1)); // 0
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: @mr.nobody please upvote the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score -1):

`btnVal` is checked to hold a value of some known `operators` (like '+', '-', etc)

Than operators.indexOf(btnVal) > -1 reads "Is this a known operator?"